# Magento 2 Cron PHP Parse Error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, crontab

I'm setting up a **Magento 2.1.3** site, first time using M2.

I'm having issues setting up my **crontab** to **re-index** etc., looking online it seems that it is a fairly common problem although all of the obvious fixes I found online did not work for me.

Info: 
Dedicated Server, OS CentOS 6.9, Plesk Onyx 17.0.17

PHP CLI: 5.4.45, Plesk Set PHP: 7.0.18

I've setup the cron info following the DevDocs as seen:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg

However this of course did not work, so delving deeper into it, I then tried manually running the cron job such as:

```
./magento indexer:reindex
```

And I get a PHP Parse error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/ts_store/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 411
```

Upon searching, the only issues I can find similar relating to the PHP Parse error are people struggling to install M2 and have been no help for me.

Is anyone able to suggest anything to help?

**UPDATE**

**I am now running PHP 5.6 CLI.**
However I am still experiencing issues, If I force the reindex using: `./magento indexer:reindex`
The reindex works, however when I setup the cron its not working and I get an undelivered email with an error station permission denied:

```
/bin/sh: /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/ts_store/var/log/setup.cron.log: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use higher PHP version CLI in command line. You can ask hosting support regarding how to use that higher version CLI in commmand line.

Comment: I am now running PHP 5.6 CLI.
However I am still experiencing issues, If I force the reindex using: ./magento indexer:reindex
The reindex works, however when I setup the cron its not working and I get an undelivered email with an error station permission denied: 
/bin/sh: /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/ts_store/var/log/setup.cron.log: Permission denied